# how to change layout for whole site in DotNetNuke 7

Tags: content-management-system, dotnetnuke

I have just started learning DNN. I dug a little into this but I just can't change the layout for whole site. I am using Awesome cycle template as starting.

I need to redesign site header and footer. If I made change in `Skins\Gravity\Home.ascx` then these changes are only appearing to my home file.

I can change the CSS the way I want but I am just unable to change the base html of header in entire site. (like we do in master pages in ASP.NET or layout in MVC)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem probably has to do with DNN supporting different skins for different pages.

You have to check if all pages use the same skin. I think that in DNN7 default site template pages use different skins. You can check this if you go to Edit Page -> Page Appearance -> Page skin

If you set all the pages to use the Gravity skin, then changes you make at the .ascx file will apply to all pages.

A uniform way to change the layout for the whole site is to set every page skin to 'None specified' and then only select skins from Admin -> Site Settings -> Basic Settings ->Appearance ->site skin.

Answer (score 1):

You can update the DNN database using an update query on the Tabs table:

```
update Tabs set SkinSrc = REPLACE(SkinSrc,'OldSkinName','NewSkinName') 
where SkinSrc like '%OldSkinName%'
```

You can also rename the containers using a similar query:

```
update TabModules set ContainerSrc = '[G]Containers/MySkin/NewContainer.ascx' 
where ContainerSrc = '[G]Containers/MySkin/OldContainer.ascx'
```

In the latest operation remember to clean the dnn cache using : Host > Host Settings > Advanced Settings > Performance Settings , click on the “Clear cache” button.